# Sign with keystore then publish with maven-publish

Tags: android, maven, gradle, maven-publish

I want to publish an Android library (`.aar`) to a Maven Repository. I manage to do it using the `signing` and `maven-publish` gradle plugins. But the signing plugin does not seem to work with a keystore file: it seems to take something like this:

```
signing.keyId=24875D73
signing.password=secret
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/me/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

and what I have are a `.keystore` file, a `keyAlias` (which looks more like “key0” than a PGP key), then a store password and a key password.

So instead of using the signing plugin, I thought I could do something more like this:

```kotlin
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        def aarPath = "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/XXX-release.aar"

        task.doLast {
            ant.signjar(
                    alias: android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias,
                    jar: aarPath,
                    keystore: android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile,
                    storepass: android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword,
                    keypass: android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword,
                    preservelastmodified: 'true')

            ant.verifyjar(
                    alias: android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias,
                    jar: aarPath,
                    keystore: android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile,
                    storepass: android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword,
                    keypass: android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)
        }
    }
}
```

This works when I do `./gradlew assembleRelease` (i.e. I can verify with jarsigner that the aar is signed). But when I do `./gradlew publish`, somehow my output aar is not signed. Which confuses me because I thought that the publish task would run the assembleRelease task, which would run the signing.

What am I missing? How can I sign my aar with a keystore and still push it to a Maven Repository?

Comment: What does `--dry-run` yield on the two?  It's not definite, mind you, but can give some clue.  Likely, the task order is changing on you.  I tracked one down recently that `--dry-run` reported incorrectly by adding a `doLast { println "taskname" }` on a couple tasks to verify the order they were actually being executed.  `G8.0.2`

Comment: I added a `println(task.name)` in `tasks.whenTaskAdded` above, and `assembleRelease` is added a lot earlier than the publishing stuff. It feels (but I have no clue, really guessing) like somehow the publish task rebuilds it, and it loses the signature. Could it be?

Comment: Next, you can add `tasks.signMavenJavaPublication.doLast {println{"signed"}}` somewhere in your file and see where that comes out in various paths...  Exact task name can vary depending on config.  Then, see where it's coming out.  Generally, gradle tasks "cant" re-run...  just in general.  Which is also why if the signing goes off when you don't expect it, and the assemble overwrites it, or its after publish, or some other unexpected order, you can at least know what it's doing and then apply some `.dependsOn` or `.finalizedBy` to force the order.

Comment: I think you were right! It seems to work if I use `if (task.name == 'assembleRelease' || task.name == 'bundleReleaseAar') {`! I thought I had tried it before, but well... as you said, the order seems to change somehow. Do you want to write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, change to:

`if (task.name == 'assembleRelease' || task.name == 'bundleReleaseAar') {`

The problem is the task order is getting changed.  Tasks don't "re-run", but certain influences can cause the tasks you're interested in to be applied an an inappropriate time (perhaps trying to sign the artifact before it's created).

Even `--dry-run` isn't guaranteed to show you the actual order, as I found out recently (in `G8.0.2`).

You can debug the actual order by adding things like this to see the actual order when it runs:

> `tasks.assembleRelease.doLast {println{"signed"}}`

and

> `tasks.signMavenJavaPublication.doLast {println{"signed"}}`

Then, run the build in ways that "work" and ways that "don't", and observe the actual order, and see how it differs from what you expect.

Comment: Can you add that in this case I had to change the if condition to `if (task.name == 'assembleRelease' || task.name == 'bundleReleaseAar') {`? That would be the actual solution :-)